# FFmpeg filter_complex ass subtitle and watermark is not working together

Tags: video, encoding, ffmpeg, video-processing

I have been trying to add logo and subtitle to a video together. But I couldn't manage it. Logo is adding successfully. But subtitles are missing on the output video. Also logo fade effect is not working.

```
ffmpeg -i '. $dest .' -i /www/otoconv/logo.png -filter_complex \ "[0:v][1:v]overlay=main_w/2-overlay_w/2:main_h/2-overlay_h/2:enable=between(t\,120\,130);[0:v]ass='.$ass_path.';[1:v]fade=out:st=30:d=1:alpha=1"  -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset ultrafast -threads 0  -c:a libfaac -movflags faststart '.$out
```

Video details:

```
Duration: 00:44:51.44, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2892 kb/s
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
Stream #0:1: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 384 kb/s (default)
```

Also when i start encoding the ffmpeg output is like this

```
Output #0, mp4, to '/www/otoconv/media_subtitled/183502046hen.mp4':
Metadata:
encoder         : Lavf56.3.100
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 23.98 fps, 24k tbn, 23.98 tbc
Metadata:
  encoder         : Lavc56.0.101 libx264
Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 23.98 fps, 24k tbn, 23.98 tbc
Metadata:
  encoder         : Lavc56.0.101 libx264
Stream #0:2: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv444p, 308x93 [SAR 1:1 DAR 308:93], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc
Metadata:
  encoder         : Lavc56.0.101 libx264
Stream #0:3: Audio: aac (libfaac) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  encoder         : Lavc56.0.101 libfaac
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 (h264) -> overlay:main (graph 0)
Stream #0:0 (h264) -> ass (graph 0)
Stream #1:0 (png) -> overlay:overlay (graph 0)
Stream #1:0 (png) -> fade (graph 0)
overlay (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
ass (graph 0) -> Stream #0:1 (libx264)
fade (graph 0) -> Stream #0:2 (libx264)
Stream #0:1 -> #0:3 (ac3 (native) -> aac (libfaac))
```

There is no error appears during the process. Thanks in advance.

Note: I have to use ass subtitles.

Comment: Please include the **complete** `ffmpeg` console output.

Answer (score 1):

I think:

```
ffmpeg -i '. $dest .' -i /www/otoconv/logo.png -filter_complex \
"[1:v]fade=out:st=30:d=1:alpha=1[tmp_fade]; \
[0:v][tmp_fade]overlay=main_w/2-overlay_w/2:main_h/2-overlay_h/2:enable=between(t\,120\,130)[tmp_overlay]; \
[tmp_overlay]ass='.$ass_path.'[out]" \
 -map [out] -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset ultrafast -threads 0  -c:a libfaac -movflags faststart '.$out
```

should work better. Basically, you need to chain all your commands (well, technically, it is a graph and you need to be able to get from all entering nodes to the end node, but I am no mathematician so this explanation might be lacking). I do not understand ffmpeg enough to tell you why your command did not fail, but judging from the output of your file, I think that what happens is that only this chain makes it to the final video:

```
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 (h264) -> overlay:main (graph 0)
Stream #1:0 (png) -> overlay:overlay (graph 0)
overlay (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
```

These two get computed but they are lost:

```
Stream #1:0 (png) -> fade (graph 0)
Stream #0:0 (h264) -> ass (graph 0)
```

I have not run the example so I hope there is no typo.